# How to Insert Core Data Record Related to Another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios6

Currently I have two entities in my model; Module and Level. They have one to many relationship e.g. a level can have a lot of modules. How can can I insert data so that they are related one to another so that I can say that module has specific year. I need this so that when I delete module it also deletes a year.

Module<<---->Level

If I just add objects separately it works fine, but I add last line of code application crashes it says that entity Module is not key value coding compliant for the key level_number which is the name of relationship on the Module side.

```
NSManagedObject *newModule;
newModule = [NSEntityDescription
              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Module"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newModule setValue:textModuelTitle.text forKey:@"name"];
[newModule setValue:value forKey:@"credit"];

    NSManagedObject *newLevel;
    newLevel = [NSEntityDescription
                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Level"
                 inManagedObjectContext:context];
       [newLevel setValue:year forKey:@"value"];

    [[newModule mutableSetValueForKey:@"level_number"] addObject:newLevel];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have one to many relationship, set the values from one side and `Core Data` would take care of the other side.

Since a level has one to one relationship to module. Set module to a level and then save the context.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your entire crash message.

Double check your relationship is setUp correctly. Sometimes the simulator may hold on to the old coreData structure. Try deleting the application from it and re run.